# Ways of submitting HTTP requests in a web document?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, http-verbs

I want to build up a list of ways to cause HTTP submissions in a web document (HTML, Javascript, etc.)  Here's what I have so far, with the HTTP verb(s) that can be used:

- `A` links (GET)
- `FORM`s (GET, POST)
- `AJAX` requests (All HTTP verbs)

Are there any other ways to submit things via HTTP in a web document?  And are there any other verb(s) that can be used with the above methods that I haven't listed?  In particular it would be cool if you could specify a method for `A` links - I'd like to have the browser submit a `DELETE` request for some of my `A` links which delete things.

Comment: "Are there any other ways to submit things via HTTP in a web document?" — Lots. This isn't really a suitable question for Stackoverflow. It's too open ended and doesn't address any problem.

Comment: Please, don't let any link directly change or delete data unless you are really sure that no index script (e.g. search engines) will inspect your site! However, it's still dangerous if someone shares a link which deletes data for the logged-in user.

Comment: @ComFreek How would you suggest it be done then?  Via JavaScript?

Comment: @Quentin I disagree.  You say "lots" but give no examples.  I think there are a finite, relatively small, number of ways to do it.  Therefore, a definitive, objective answer can be given to the question.  And it addresses the problem I have of how best to get a "delete" button on my page.  I can think of a couple of hacky ways to do it, but for all I know there is a better way to submit the DELETE request to the server that I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Jez This kind of security holes are called 'Cross-site request forgery' (or short: 'CSRF'). Here is a good starting point: https://owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add

- [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)
- Post/Get using browser plugins (Flash, Java, etc...)